# Planning for PhD, How much Master's thesis topic and coursework matter for PhD?

Tags: phd

I am a master's student in computer science. I have almost completed my coursework and they are to different fields. I am planning to do a PhD in the future: is a master's thesis an important prerequisite for a PhD?

I exactly don't know which field to select for the thesis, I like databases, but my previous job experience was in quality assurance. I really don't want to go for hardcore programming kind of field of research.

Kindly help me with selection of my field.

Comment: Your question is not clear, and might depend on your location. In some countries, you cannot do a PhD without a completed Master degree, and you cannot get a Master degree without a Master thesis, so yes, a Master thesis is an important prerequisite. Also, you should be able to know which topic you want to work on, and probably discuss about that with your advisor.

Comment: A master's degree is just an administrative hurdle (which, as Charles points out, you might or might not be required to jump, depending on your country).  What matters is **evidence of potential for research**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regards to your first query, any and all **relevant** prior research and work experience will strengthen any PhD application.  It is often expected that you can show that you have some proven knowledge (and skills) in the field that you are intending to research.

I would advise you to research PhD topics, finding an academic that specialising in that field and ask them about your prior study, also ask the admissions people.

No one can really answer the final part of your query, as this will be up to your interests and experience.  But, one thing to consider for this - perhaps try and find a field that is a mixture of your interests and experience.